# HTTP error code 500

Tags: java

I am trying to run a Java client application which in turn calls a servlet, and both of them are placed on the same machine. While running the client code I am getting:

```
Error while making connection
```

And the server returned HTTP response code is 500.

See URL: https://psng11d19087.ksfg.ds-group.com:443

Any tips on how I can start debugging this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The very first step would be to look into the server error log to see what the problem was.

Answer (score 3):

First thing to do is look at the server log.  500 indicates something failed in the server, and your server log should (one hopes) have exceptions listed etc.

Knowing the server would help be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem of your server or setup but this is something missing or crash from your code.

Check in the body of Error log:

you will find the targetModulenmae/ or unable resolve module ..
then try to solve that problem